# Show error message under another using a Directive. Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm doing a validation on a directive, forcing the user to check the box. If the checkbox is not marked, an error message appears. My problem is that the message shifts to the text of the checkbox.

```
style="margin-top:5px;color:red;"
```

[image]

I need the validation message at the end of the checkbox.But I do not want it to affect the presentation or that this message is above other elements.

```
style="position: absolute;margin-top:5px;color:red;"
```

[image]

I need to do this in the directive, I do not want to touch controller or template. How can do it?

```
    app.directive('validate', function ($timeout) {

        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            require: 'ngModel', 

            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
              if (!ngModel){
                return;          
              }
              ngModel.$setValidity('validation', false);

              scope.directive_function= function(){
                alert("directive function");
              }

              ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val){
                if(val==true){
                  ngModel.$setValidity('validation', true);
                  var elemento_eliminar=(angular.element((document.getElementById('errorchec' ))));
                  elemento_eliminar.remove();
                }else{
                 ngModel.$setValidity('validation', false);
                 var newDirective = angular.element('<div id="errorchec" class="span_wrong" style="margin-top:5px;color:red;">'+"must be required"+'</div>');
                 //style="position: absolute;margin-top:5px;color:red;"
                element.after(newDirective);
                }
              })
           }


        };
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2kt4ukcx/

Answer (score 0):

If it's right solution for you, it works     `style="position:absolute; top:5px;color:red;`